# How to import Mlpy on IPython?

Tags: installation, ipython

I am using IPyhton(py 3.4) notebook. I want to import mlpy module by typing import mlpy command. However I get the following error "No module named mlpy". I tried to install it by using "pip install" on the command prompt but this time I take the invalid syntax error. What should I need to do in order to install mlpy?

Comment: The invalid syntax error sounds like you were trying to use `pip install` inside a Python prompt. You should run pip from the system shell (the `C:\>` command prompt on Windows). Alternatively, you can run a system command inside IPython by putting `!` at the front, like `!pip install ...`

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding "!" before pip helped me install mlpy. However IPython installed version 0.1.0. I need to install 0.3.4 to use a function of mlpy. I tried to upgrade by "!pip install --upgrade mlpy" but nothing changed. How can I install the upgraded version on Ipython?

Comment: 0.1.0 is [the version on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mlpy). I guess you want to use [this mlpy package](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/), which isn't on PyPI. You'll have to follow the instructions to install that manually. It's unfortunate that there appear to be two distinct packages with the same name and a similar purpose.

Comment: So does it mean that I won't be able to use any version of mlpy other than 0.1.0 on IPython? Is installing the latest mlpy package manually (also installing Python 3.2+ in order to use it) the only way of using mlpy 0.3.4?

Comment: There are two completely distinct packages that happen to have the same name `mlpy`. The one I think you want is not on PyPI, so you have to install it manually. Python 3.2+ means 3.2 or above, so it should work fine with Python 3.4.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help.